# как распарсить файл на python

Tags: python

день добрый

подскажите, как распарсить текстовый файл на питоне.. файл вида:

```
первое
3 
текст | текст | текст 
текст| текст| текст 
текст| текст| текст

второе
5 
текст| текст| текст 
текст| текст | текст 
текст| текст| текст 
текст| текст | текст 
текст| текст| текст
```

необходимо по второй строке, с цифрой, продолжить парсинг, т.е. она должна указать что после нее нужно спарсить еще n-элекментов, после чего цикл должен заново спарсить 1 элемент, посмотреть сколько надо строк дальше обойти и так до конца..

на выходе нужно получить словарь где ключ будет первая строка, а значение - список из строк "текст| текст | текст"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def get_item(f):
    key = f.next().strip('\n')
    n = int(f.next().strip())
    lst = []
    for i in range(n):
        lst += f.next().strip('\n').split('|')
    return key, lst


data = {}
with open('test.txt') as f:
    while True:
        try:
            key, lst = get_item(f)
            data[key] = lst
            next(f)
        except StopIteration:
            break
print data
```

test.txt:

```
item1
2
text|text|text
text|text

item2
3
txt|txt
txt|xxx|txt
txt|txt
```

Вывод:

```
{'item2': ['txt', 'txt', 'txt', 'xxx', 'txt', 'txt', 'txt'], 'item1': ['text', 'text', 'text', 'text', 'text']}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lines = [line.strip() for line in open('123.txt')]
result = {lines[n-1]: lines[n+1: n+1+int(lines[n])]
          for n in range(len(lines)) if lines[n].isnumeric()}
```